# Asus FX516 laptop and backlit keys

Tags: keyboard, asus

I have installed Ubuntu 23.04 (lunar) and would like to be able to use the backlit keys capability however rogauracore does not work - cannot find keyboard and openrgb fails with unmet packages but cannot find anywhere what the unmet packages are does anyone know what or where I can find what these packages are or what I need to install ?

Thanks